# Apache Ignite C# Client Connection configuration for kubernetes

Tags: c#, kubernetes, ignite

We are following the below article to establish C# client connection to the Ignite Cluster, both of them deployed in the Kubernetes.

https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/installation/kubernetes/amazon-eks-deployment#creating-service

We do not find the equivalent C# class/method to perform the connection configuration in the C# client application.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJ3Gq.png)

Please help us to find alternate methods to do the connection configuration for Kubernetes.

Comment: is it thick or thin .NET client?

Comment: We have thick and thin .Net clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This API is not yet available for .NET, the [relevant ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-13011) is in progress and most likely will be included into the next release.

For now, you can list a set of server IPs for your thin clients explicitly. And for your server and thick client nodes it's fine to rely on spring.xml configuration. More details [here](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/net-specific/net-configuration-options#configure-with-spring-xml).

Example:

```
 var cfg = new IgniteConfiguration
 {
    ...
    SpringConfigUrl = "/path/to/spring.xml"
  };
```

And your spring configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">

        <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes. -->
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <!--
                        Enables Kubernetes IP finder and setting custom namespace and service names.
                    -->
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder">
                        <property name="namespace" value="ignite"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Thank you Alexandr Shapkin. We shall try this alternate.

Comment: We got error on Ignite start. I have posted a different question with the details in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72028479/error-in-apache-ignite-c-sharp-client-connection-for-kubernetes.