# Error in Apache Ignite C# Client connection for kubernetes

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, .net-core, ignite

We followed the solution suggested in [Apache Ignite C# Client Connection configuration for kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71957287/apache-ignite-c-sharp-client-connection-configuration-for-kubernetes) as thick client to connect the ignite cluster running in kubrenetes.

We get the below error message on start:

failed to start: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'dlopen' in shared library 'libcoreclr.so'. at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.Jni.DllLoader.NativeMethodsCore.dlopen(String filename, Int32 flags) at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.Jni.DllLoader.Load(String dllPath) at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.Jni.JvmDll.LoadDll(String filePath, String simpleName) at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.Jni.JvmDll.Load(String configJvmDllPath, ILogger log) at Apache.Ignite.Core.Ignition.Start(IgniteConfiguration cfg)

We included the openjdk8 in the docker image. Here is the docker file.

`````
#FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
#WORKDIR /app
#EXPOSE 80
#EXPOSE 443

ARG REPO=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime
FROM $REPO:3.1.24-alpine3.15 AS base
# Install ASP.NET Core
RUN aspnetcore_version=3.1.24 \
    && wget -O aspnetcore.tar.gz https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/aspnetcore/Runtime/$aspnetcore_version/aspnetcore-runtime-$aspnetcore_version-linux-musl-x64.tar.gz \
    && aspnetcore_sha512='1341b6e0a9903b253a69fdf1a60cd9e6be8a5c7ea3c4a52cd1a8159461f6ba37bef7c2ae0d6df5e1ebd38cd373cf384dc55c6ef876aace75def0ac77427d3bb0' \
    && echo "$aspnetcore_sha512  aspnetcore.tar.gz" | sha512sum -c - \
    && tar -oxzf aspnetcore.tar.gz -C /usr/share/dotnet ./shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App \
    && rm aspnetcore.tar.gz

RUN apk add openjdk8
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk
ENV PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:${PATH}"

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
...
RUN dotnet restore "API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "API"
RUN dotnet build "API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final


WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "API.dll"]````
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Ignite issue on Alpine Linux was fixed in 2.13, which was released yesterday - please try upgrading.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-16749
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Apache.Ignite/2.13.0

---

Additionally, set **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** environment variable:

- **openjdk8**: `ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib/jvm/default-jvm/jre/lib/amd64/server`
- **openjdk11**: `ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib/jvm/default-jvm/jre/lib/server`

Do not set `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` - it is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you Pavel Tupitsyn. We shall try this with 2.13.

Comment: We got the below error with 2.13. Can you help us here?

failed to start: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libjvm.so' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: Error loading shared library liblibjvm.so: No such file or directory
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.Jni.JvmDll.JniNativeMethodsLinux.JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs(IntPtr& pvm, Int32 size, Int32& size2)
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Unmanaged.Jni.JvmDll.GetCreatedJvms(IntPtr& pvm, Int32 size, Int32& size2)

Comment: We are using alpine3.10. We shall try with alpine3.15.

Comment: Looks like you don't have Java installed. The Dockerfile above sets JAVA_HOME but the base image does not have Java binaries.

Comment: We updated the docker file to get the openjdk and set JAVA_HOME. Here I posted the updated docker file.

Comment: Same error with alpine3.15 as well.

Comment: We could run a sample java application there.

Comment: @Prem I've updated the answer. Please set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as described, and remove `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH`. I've tested this with your Dockerfile and it works.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Pavel Tupitsyn. Now we get the below error, failed to start: Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.IgniteException: Java exception occurred [class=java.lang.NoSuchFieldError, message=logger]
---> Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.JavaException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: logger
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:865)

Comment: We initialized the logger in the ignite configuration constructor to avoid this error, it did not help.

Comment: Please do a clean build of your application (delete bin and obj directories). Then rebuild everything. Looks like there are duplicate jar files from previous Ignite versions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55408181/apache-ignite-net-node-would-not-start-when-a-spring-configuration-file-is-used

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Now the Start method is not throwing any errors, but the call is not getting finished for a long time and not returning the IIgnite instance. Checked the sever node log and could not find anything there.

Comment: Most likely an issue with network configuration - the node can't bind to a port or connect to the cluster. What's in the log?

Comment: Here is the log in cluster node, [SEVERE][main][TcpDiscoverySpi] Failed to get registered addresses from IP finder (retrying every 2000ms; change 'reconnectDelay' to configure the frequency of retries) [maxTimeout=0]
class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to retrieve Ignite pods IP addresses.
at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.getRegisteredAddresses(TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.java:80)

Comment: Above log was retrieved using the kubectl logs command. When we checked the log file inside /ignite/work/log/, it looks fine.

[08:06:18,754][INFO][grid-timeout-worker-#22][IgniteKernal]
Metrics for local node (to disable set 'metricsLogFrequency' to 0)
^-- Node [id=3949c8f8, uptime=00:21:00.680]
^-- Cluster [hosts=2, CPUs=2, servers=2, clients=0, topVer=2, minorTopVer=1]
^-- Network [addrs=[10.1.0.40, 127.0.0.1], discoPort=47500, commPort=47100]
^-- CPU [CPUs=1, curLoad=13.67%, avgLoad=17.54%, GC=0%]
^-- Heap [used=73MB, free=97.61%, comm=193MB]

Comment: "Failed to retrieve Ignite pods IP addresses" - this is the problem. Please ask a separate question regarding `TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder` setup.

Comment: Thank you Pavel Tupitsyn for your help on troubleshooting this issue. I have created another query for the issue with TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72096400/apache-ignite-error-failed-to-retrieve-ignite-pods-ip-addresses

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Pavel's response, instead of building your own docker image, you can utilize base image available in GridGain edition: https://hub.docker.com/r/gridgain/community-dotnet

GridGain Community edition is built on Apache Ignite, is free and open source as well. You might check the official docs for more details.

Comment: Thank you Alexandr Shapkin for the suggestion.