# Apache Ignite error - Failed to retrieve Ignite pods IP addresses

Tags: kubernetes, ignite

We followed the article https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/installation/kubernetes/amazon-eks-deployment#creating-service and setup the Ignite Cluster in the Kubernetes.

We were unable to establish the connection from the client application which is deployed in a different POD to this Ignite Cluster using TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.

We saw the below errors in the Ignite Cluster node,

[SEVERE][main][TcpDiscoverySpi] Failed to get registered addresses from IP finder (retrying every 2000ms; change 'reconnectDelay' to configure the frequency of retries) [maxTimeout=0] class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException:
Failed to retrieve Ignite pods IP addresses. at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.getRegisteredAddresses(TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.java:80)

Here is the spring.xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="discoverySpi">
          <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
              <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder">
                <property name="namespace" value="ignite-namespace" />
                <property name="serviceName" value="ignite-service" />
              </bean>
            </property>
          </bean>
        </property>
      </bean>
</beans>
```

We specified the namespace and service names in the deployment files,

**cluster-role.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: ignite
  namespace: ignite-namespace
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources: # Here are the resources you can access
      - pods
      - endpoints
    verbs: # That is what you can do with them
      - get
      - list
      - watch
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: ignite
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: ignite
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: ignite
    namespace: ignite-namespace
```

**ignite-service.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  # The name must be equal to KubernetesConnectionConfiguration.serviceName
  name: ignite-service
  # The name must be equal to KubernetesConnectionConfiguration.namespace
  namespace: ignite-namespace
  labels:
    app: ignite
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: rest
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
    - name: thinclients
      port: 10800
      targetPort: 10800
  # The pod-to-service routing is required for apps that are not deployed in K8
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
  selector:
    # Must be equal to the label set for pods.
    app: ignite
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: I think we'd need to see your configuration. The error suggests it can't read from the Kubernetes API, which suggests you missed the cluster role but it could be a number of things.

Comment: Stephen Darlington, I have updated the configurations here, please check them.

Comment: any update on this issue ?